# Copy all the child elements except one in XSLT without copying whole XML

Tags: xslt

I have searched to copy child elements except one or change the value of the tag. Everywhere below templates are used to copy all the XML and then 
apply templates to remove one element.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="part"/>
```

I have a XML like below

```
<root>
    <a1>
    ...
    </a1>
    <a2>
    ....
    </a2>
    <a3>
        <a31>1</a31>
        <a32>2</a32>
        <a33>
            <a331>3</a331>
            <a332>5</a332>
            ...
            <a339>10</a339>
        </a33>
        <a33>
            <a331>4</a331>
            <a332>6</a332>
            ...
            <a339>56</a339>
        </a33>
        <a34>
            <a331>3</a331>
            ....
        </a34>
    </a3>
</root>
```

I have written xslt like this

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:element name="root">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="root"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:element name="a1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="a1"/>
    </xsl:element>
    ...
    <xsl:if test="a3!=''">
        <xsl:if test="((a3/a33[a331='3']!='') or (a3/a33[a331='3']!=''))">
            <xsl:element name="a3">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="a3"/>
            </xsl:elememt>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a3" >      
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[a331='3']" mode="copy"></xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="copy">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a331">
    <xsl:element name="a331">
        <xsl:value-of select="4">
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

I would like to get output xml like below.

```
<root>
    <a1>
    ...
    </a1>
    <a2>
    ....
    </a2>
    <a3>
        <a31>1</a31>
        <a32>2</a32>
        <a33>
            <a331>4</a331>
            <a332>5</a332>
            ...
            <a339>10</a339>
        </a33>      
        <a34>
            <a331>4</a331>
            ....
        </a34>
    </a3>
</root>
```

could you please someone explain how to achieve this without copying whole XML first place?

Comment: Could you explain in few words the *logic* behind this transformation? I find the example confusing.

Comment: I want to copy all the child elements and it's value except one based on the value of child element. I want to copy all the child elements of <a33> if <a33><a331> contains 3 and change the value of <a331> to 4.

Comment: "*if <a33><a331> contains 3*"  I am afraid that's not quite clear.

Comment: I mean if value of <a33>.<a331> contains 3 then select all the child elements of <a33> except <a331> and change the value of this element(<a331>) to another value say 4.

Answer (score 3):

There are two fundamental XSLT strategies: start from nothing and build the output by adding nodes explicitly, or start by copying everything and add only changes. There can be little doubt that in your case the latter strategy is the more efficient one.

If I understand your requirements correctly, there are only two (relatively minor) changes you want to make:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="a33[not(a331=3)]"/>

<xsl:template match="a331">
    <a331>4</a331>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to the following **test input**:

```
<root>
    <a1/>
    <a2/>
    <a3>
        <a31>1</a31>
        <a32>2</a32>
        <a33>
            <a331>3</a331>
            <a332>5</a332>
            <a339>7</a339>
        </a33>
        <a33>
            <a331>4</a331>
            <a332>6</a332>
            <a339>8</a339>
        </a33>
        <a34>
            <a331>3</a331>
        </a34>
    </a3>
</root>
```

the **result** will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <a1/>
   <a2/>
   <a3>
      <a31>1</a31>
      <a32>2</a32>
      <a33>
         <a331>4</a331>
         <a332>5</a332>
         <a339>7</a339>
      </a33>
      <a34>
         <a331>4</a331>
      </a34>
   </a3>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. how to transform it by first strategy by adding nodes? Because I'm using large XML, I don't want to copy all the elements in the first place.

Comment: @Mohan Not sure what you mean by "large XML". Are there **other** branches that do not appear in your example - or is it only a matter of how many of the **same** elements you have shown us are there?

Comment: yes. I just included some of the branches in the example. <a1> has more than 100 child elements.I'm transforming using first strategy applied logic for each elements i need. If you see my XSLT i traverse each element and creating nodes that i need. I struck where i need all the child elements of particular parent based on value present in child elements and i also don't know all the possible child elements of that parent node. Hope you understand?Thanks.

Comment: @Mohan I don't think it makes much difference, since those elements to which you apply special logic are excluded from being copied as default anyway.